# How to understand the mass in the definition of momentum in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, mass

I am looking at the definition of momentum in Griffiths, which is $$\langle p \rangle = m\frac{d\langle x\rangle}{dt}.$$ So as I understand it, the velocity here tells us the rate of change for the expectation of x, which is like how we can expect the distribution for x to change with time evolution. What I am wondering is how to imagine what this momentum is under this picture? In classical mechanics, I would imagine how there's some kind of "power" (in colloquial terms, not physical terms) an object has that is reflected by how fast it's going and how resistant it is to change that motion, but I'm not sure how to combine mass with this idea of rate of change of expectation to form a coherent picture.

Comment: It's basically the same. Is there some reason you expect otherwise?